# Tryvalidatemodel in asp.net core webapi throwing null referenceexception in unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a simple asp.net core 2.0 webapi. I have a model and also getting a value from header. i set the model property inside the controller action and do the model validation as below.

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Search(AggregateSearchCriteria criteria)
{
    var providers = Request.Headers["providers"];

    criteria.Providers = providers.ToString().Split(',').ToList();

    ModelState.Clear();

    //fails here

    TryValidateModel(criteria);

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    return ok();
}
```

It works fine, but when i write unit test, it is failinga at TryValidateModel line. I can see some help in google but doesn't seems to help me.

Can anyone help how to fix this?

The error in unit test is:

> AggregateSearchControllerTests.TestAggregateSearchWithValidData threw exception: 
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Thanks

Comment: What is the error? most likely it is missing some context that is usually provided at runtime that is not available when unit testing.

Comment: Maybe this will help https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/8640

Comment: @Nkosi I am setting one of the property of the model inside the action method, so without clearing the modelstate, it wont revalidate with the latest model.

Comment: @MukilDeepthi but that will remove any other modelstate errors. Just remove the one you edited.

Comment: @xneg and Nkosi that link solved the issue. T

Comment: @Nkosi oh is it? how to remove that particualr one?

Comment: @MukilDeepthi `if(ModelState.ContainsKey("Providers") ModelState.Remove("Providers");`